# Can I easily replace the Throttle Position Sensor on a 1999 Maxima?

Tags: nissan, obd-ii, sensor, maxima, throttle-position-sensor

My '99 Maxima's `Check Engine` light came on recently. I whipped out my OBD-II reader, and pulled off two codes.

```
P0325 (Knock Sensor)
```

and

```
P1705 (TPS)
```

Reading online it appears the knock sensor code is pretty certainly a side-effect of the TPS code. And the common symptoms of TPS (e.g. sputtering while idle) are occurring in my car. I'm pretty certain I could mechanically replace the TPS myself, looking at directions and pictures online, but what I'm unsure of is whether this is repair as simple as just swapping the part out, or if the on-board computers need some kind of recalibration or something afterwards, in which case I'd just take it to the shop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a modern car, there's no real work to be done after physically replacing the part.

You can disconnect the negative battery for 10-15 mins to reset the computer and have it relearn its mappings, but that's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info; good to know. Unfortunately my car is still old enough that it has an adjustable TPS, so since I need to bring the car in anyway, I'm going to have them deal with this also, instead of futzing with trying to get the adjustment right.